# I can't install it from flash drive

Tags: system-installation

I made a working flash drive to boot ubuntu from ( I've used it in another computer and it worked) and I can't install it on my laptop.

When I restart de laptop with the flash drive in, I just get a beep from the laptop and I can't select any option from the ubuntu installation menu that appears.

Is it some mistake in my hard drive? how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please add the brand and type of your laptop. Without it, we'd have to guess. Did you select the flash drive as startup device when booting?

Comment: Hello,

Yeah, i select  the boot to have priority for a flash drive and i can boot from the flash drive. What happens is that it opens the menu of ubuntu with the different options: try ubuntu; install ubuntu; etc but i can't choose anything and the laptop doesn't recognize anything i do. My only solution is to turn off the laptop and disconnect the flash drive in order to enter windows again

My laptop is an acer 64-bit

Comment: Which Acer 64bit laptop do you have? They must have more than one type :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your laptop BIOS to make sure it will allow you to boot from a flash drive. Maybe have the BIOS check for a flash drive before the HDD.

If your laptop is too old, the BIOS may not allow you to boot from a flash drive.

Comment: I have the bios to boot from the flash drive because i want to install ubuntu.. And it boots from the flash drive, it opens the menu with the different options: test ubuntu; install ubuntu; etc.. But it happens what i said, only a beep and the computer doesn't respond to anything. I have to turn it off and disconnect the flash drive to use windows again